# How to display pages with different header?

Tags: php, css, web-deployment

I am working on website for my school project. But I came across with a problem. I display a header in every page. One of my header contains login form and other one contains username, search bar, etc..

The questions is, there are 3 pages; faq, contact, about. And I want to show them either user is logged in or not. But the headers are problem. I want user to see the header-after-login if user is logged in if not I wanna show header-before-login.

I have the code any everything. I need a way or a logic to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: SImple condition: `if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) {echo 'header after login';} else {echo 'header before login';}`

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention something. I display sidebar after user logged in. So, the width of the faq, contact, about is gonna be problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a million and one ways to solve this, and I'm assuming you're able to programatically find out if the user is logged in.

faq.php, contact.php, about.php:

```
include 'header.php';
//content
include 'footer.php';
```

header.php:

```
echo '<!doctype html><html>...';
if($user_is_logged_in == true) {
    echo '<body class="logged_in">You are logged in!';
    include 'sidebar.php';
} else {
    echo '<body class="not_logged_in">You are not logged in!';
    include 'user_not_logged_in_header.php';
}
echo '<div class="main">';
```

footer.php:

```
echo '</div></body></html>';
```

sidebar.php:

```
echo '<div class="sidebar">Sidebar!</div>;
```

Then the sidebar div and main div can be independently controlled using the classes.

Comment: I display sidebar after user logged in. So, the width of the faq, contact, about is gonna be problem.

Comment: So I updated it. Without knowing the detail of incompatibility between the pages it's difficult to know exactly what structure will work best for you (perhaps your structure would support completely separate pages for logged in vs not logged int). But the above will give you enough delineation to allow independent styling of logged in vs not logged in assuming the HTML structures can match in that way.

Comment: I guess I am gonna use the way you showed to me. Just need to modify it little bit to make it work with sidebar. I also thought about using width:auto instead of giving exact value for width. Although, I don't know if width auto will work for me. Let's see. If I figure out a good way to do it, I am going to share here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
header();

function header(){
   $header = "<div ";
   if($_SESSION['userID']){
      $header .= "class=\"header user_info_header\"";
      $content = "logged user info";
   }else{
      $header .= "class=\"header login_form_header\"";
      $content = "login form";
   }
   $header .= ">".$content."</div>";
   echo $header; 
}
```

Comment: Header size is different and has different designs, so I won't be able to use this.

Comment: u can style header using css class indentificator
.header - global style for header
.user_info_header and .login_form_header are specific class